# Failed in execute of "lsscsi" command

Tags: command, scsi

I can't execute the "lsscsi" command in linux, I keep getting "command not found" when I try to run it. 
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you be more specific and add the output?

Comment: When i execute that command it is displaying as "command not found"

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# lsb_release
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch

Comment: I can't use that information

Comment: So what i need to do ? could you please specify me the command to get the details you needed inorder to reslove the issue.

Comment: First use cat /etc/*-release then post the output back

Comment: Do you still got this issue?

Comment: The issue is resolved. Thnaks CedianO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the package "lsscsi". You can run `yum install lsscsi` (on Red Hat based distributions) or `apt-get install lsscsi` (on Debian based distributions).